# Should I use a class name when referencing a static field in that class?

Tags: java, static

If I have a class with a static field such as:

```
public class Foo {
    public static int bar;
}
```

...And I want to reference this field within its declared class. I am aware that both:

```
public class Foo {
    public static int bar;

    public static int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Foo {
    public static int bar;

    public static int getBar() {
        return Foo.bar;
    }
}
```

work. Is there any preference or convention between whether or not to include the class name like that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This must have been asked here before, but I prefer the first version.  That it is a static method already means we know that any class-related field which is returned must be static, and cannot be an instance member.

Comment: Of course, why you would even have a getter method for a public static field is another question...

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS It was just an example method.

Comment: I think he just wanted to reference the static field from within the declared method.
And there's no need to reference a static field using the class qualifier when called from within a declared method.

Comment: You'll only be required to qualify it (second version) if there's potential for ambiguity (such as same static field/method in superclass). But I personally prefer to always qualify my references (yes, that's only a preference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with whatever being mentioned in the comments. Apart from this, I keep readability of the code in mind and then decide. Following code fragment gives an idea on the same:

```
public class Engine {
    private static boolean isOn = false;

    public static void doWork1() {
        if (isOn) { // check if engine is on
            // do some work
        }
    }

    public static void doWork2() {
        if (Engine.isOn) {
            // do some work
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You can see that `doWork2()` method by using the class name increased the code readability even without adding any comment to the code.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, its totally opinion based. You should do whatever method you prefer. Both are equally granted. But I would like to add one point, if you are using getter/setter, then declare the static variable private:

```java
public class Foo {
    private static int bar;

    public static int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
    public static int setBar(int _bar) {
        bar = _bar;
    }
}
```

And as the both getter and setter methods are static, it ensures, they both definitely work with only static variables of `Foo` class. This solves readability problem too.